# JS Cookie to Show/Hide form depending on user

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set up a website where anyone can access it after filling out a form. I already set up the form with a few fields but my question is how can I use a JS cookie to check if the user has already submitted this form, if it has redirect them to the next page, if not wait until they submit the form and then redirect?

***The data from the form does not need to be saved yet, this will be implemented later.***

**Desired functionality**: User opens website, if they have submitted the form before, they just go straight to index page, if they are a new user who has not submitted the form, they fill it out, submit, and are redirected to the index page. Cookie expires in 6 months.

My code that doesn't seem to be working:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + exdays * 30 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
      }

      function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
        var ca = decodedCookie.split(";");
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
          var c = ca[i];
          while (c.charAt(0) == " ") {
            c = c.substring(1);
          }
          if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
          }
        }
        return "";
      }

      function checkCookie() {
        var user = getCookie("filled_form");
        if (user != "") {
          window.location.replace("https://google.com/");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="checkCookie()">
    <form id="form">
      <label for="fname">First name:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" /><br />
      <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br />
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="" /><br /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />
    </form>
    <script>
      const form = document.getElementById("form");
      form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        setCookie("filled_form", true, 60);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a "pure" HTML and JS page? Or are you using jQuery, React or some framework?

Comment: Just pure JS, but if the JQuery solution is simpler id be glad to add jquery

Comment: Can you use Node.js?

Comment: No sorry I haven't worked with node.js

Comment: No need to use Node.js if he just went to save cookies in the client side...

Comment: yeah, but passport.js just makes things lot easier.

Comment: Passaport.js is for authentication... not really what OP wants here.

Comment: I've edited the question to include my full code, I think it's not working because the cookie isn't linked to the submit button on the page or the form

Comment: Yeah, you should `setCookie` when the form is submitted.

Comment: Can you edit my code to show how to fix the issue please?

Comment: @bicycle4431, I have edited it. Sorry for the delay. Hope the new version works.

Answer (score 3):

Use `document.cookie`.

To set it:

```
document.cookie = "filledForm=true; expires=<WHEN_YOU_WANT_THE_COOKIE_TO_EXPIRE>";
```

To retrive it:

```
let cookies = document.cookie;
```

NOTE: `document.cookie` will return all cookies in one string much like: `cookie1=value; cookie2=value; cookie3=value;`. So you should split it or something like that.

To change it you should just reset it:

```
document.cookie = "filledForm=false; expires=<WHEN_YOU_WANT_THE_COOKIE_TO_EXPIRE>";
```

Check the docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). For examples check [this](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/) site

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Does filledform=true; automatically link it to the form on the page? What if there is more than one form? How can I ensure the cookie is linked to the correct form?

Comment: You can set paths to cookies. Check the link to the docs.

Comment: This thread may also help to understand more about "set" and "get" cookies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript

Comment: I've added a link to examples now.

Comment: @bicycle4431 when you said in the first comment "What if there is more than one form?", is that your case? Please be very clear in your question to get the appropriate answer :)